# Why does my Floating action button look like a small dot on the screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a floating action button on my main activity and it looks fine on the Pixel 4XL Emulator but when I put it on my Huawei P30 pro it looks like a small dot on my screen. Why?[image]

XML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#17171A">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tasksText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:text="Oversikt" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/tasksRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tasksText"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="179dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="178dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:text="Legg Til"
        app:backgroundTint="#3068DF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[[image: How it looks on my P30 pro][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXMGr.jpg)
[image: How it looks on the emulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I horizontally centered your button and removed start/end margins and alignments):

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
    android:text="Legg Til"
    app:backgroundTint="#3068DF" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width and height to wrap_content, and use `app:fabSize` attribute for setting the size of floating action Button, this attribute accept normal,small, etc.